# Xcode Localized Resources in Git Submodule

Tags: ios, xcode, git, localization, git-submodules

*I want to know what the best way is to handle localized resources, in Xcode, when you are dealing with submodules in git.  Here's what I mean:*

Let's say I have an iOS App where the files exist as an Xcode project, with various subdirectories and so on.  Let's call this the **Bananas** app.

However, I found that I needed to build **Apple**, **Grape**, and **Lemon** apps.  Luckily, a big chunk of the code in my Bananas app was reusable.

I took the reusable code from Bananas, and created a submodule in git called **Fruit**.  All four of my delectable apps have the Fruit submodule.

In the file system, it looks like this:

```
projects
└── bananas
    ├── Xcode.project
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── fruit
        ├── codeFile1
        ├── codeFile2
        ├── xib1
        └── xib2
```

Now I need to translate all four of my apps into several languages.  First, I go into Bananas and adde NSLocalizedString onto all of the code files, which includes `codeFile1` and `codeFile2` in the fruit submodule.  I also turn on Base Localization for `xib1` and `xib2`.  This moves the xib into a subfolder, `Base.lproj`, and will let me create `.strings` files via `Editor > Export for Localization`, as well as creating alternate xib files for different localizations.

Within Git, I commit these changes to my Bananas repository, and also commit the changes to the Fruit repository and update the pointer in Bananas to point at this new submodule commit.  Everything is fine and normal there.  Here's what my directory structure looks like now:

```
projects
└── bananas
    ├── Xcode.project
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── fruit
        ├── codeFile1
        ├── codeFile2
        └── Base.lproj
            ├── xib1
            └── xib2
```

However, when I start working on Apple, and update the Fruit submodule pointer to the latest version, the various directory modifications (items moved into Base.lproj) are not reflected in my `Xcode.project` file.  The files show as missing because they have been moved by me updating my Git submodule.

What is the best method to include these changes to directory structure, within the `Xcode.project` file so that I do not break the project by doing localizations within a Git submodule?

My best guess is that perhaps I could make a sub-project file for Fruit, and then include the Fruit project within each of my apps.  Is this the way this is done, or is there a better way?

Comment: Did you achieve that?

Comment: Sorry @denis_lor but I don't remember the outcome of this particular project, or how I handled the problem, if I did in fact handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have approached this in the past is to create a new `.project` for each submodule. Applications become `xcworkspace`s with an "instance" `project` and one or more submodule "base class" `project`s.

Comment: Okay, that's more or less what I thought.  Could you perhaps go into detail on exactly how you accomplish this?  I'm struggling to figure this out.  (Xcode 6.1.1)

Comment: @ian-macdonald Can you share a step by step how to do that please?